# After signing a jar (deployed as an applet) can I host that applet on any domain?

Tags: java, jar, certificate

I'm about to purchase a certificate from verisgn to sign jar files so that the publisher information is present when the user is prompted to run the java applet. Can I use the certificate that I purchase to sign jar files (that run as applets) that reside on multiple domains -- without security warnings?

I guess what I'm ultimately asking is if the certificates are restricted to a single domain. Kind of how you have to buy a wildcard SSL certificate if you want to use the same SSL cert on different domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I can use the certificate that I purchased to sign jar files even though they reside on multiple domains.

However, Java will issue a warning if the website has a self-signed certificate.